# How to convert JavaScript code to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, converters

```
symbolen.parent = object;
object.element.onclick = function() {
  this.parent.position.x = 0;
  this.parent.position.y = 0;
  this.parent.position.z = 0;
  this.parent.scale.x = 4,
  this.parent.scale.y = 4;
};
```

i want to convert the javascript code to jquery.
Because i want to use "siblings".
how can i change it ?
is there any website for that?

for example i tried this code with scale first , there is no error message, but it is not working...

```
$('object').click(function(event) {
  $(this).parent().css('scale', '4');                                                                
  $(this).parent().siblings().css('scale', '0');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @Cid but javascript is not jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap element(s) in a jQuery object with `$(element)`. Then you can do any jQuery functionality with it. I changed `'object'` selector into `object.element`. You don't use quotes here because you use the element in the variable directly instead of using a selector. Also `scale` is not a css attribute so i assume you mean `transform: scale()`

```js
//Mimic your object.element
var object = {};
object.element = document.getElementsByClassName('scale');

//Add on click handler and set scale on click.
$(object.element).click(function() {
  $(this).css("transform", "scale(4, 4)");
  $(this).siblings().css("transform", "scale(1)");
});
```

```css
div#parent {
  text-align: center;
}

div#scale {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <br>
  <div class="scale">Scale on click</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="scale">Scale on click</div>
  <br>
</div>
```