# Convert JS function to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can this JavaScript function

```
function reset() {
    var customSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select")[0];
    var select = customSelect.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    var selected = customSelect.getElementsByClassName("select-selected")[0];
    var selectedItem = customSelect.getElementsByClassName('same-as-selected')[0];

    select.selectedIndex = 0;
    selected.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    selectedItem.classList.remove('same-as-selected');
}
```

Be converted into a jQuery function?
I have tried the first variable like this:

```
  var customSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select")[0];
  var jqcustomSelect = $(".custom-select:eq(0)").html();
  console.log(customSelect + "  JQ: " + jqcustomSelect);
```

But I am confused about the output:

```
customSelect = [object HTMLDivElement]
```

While

```
jqcustomSelect = html code
```

1) How can I convert this function?

2) And why is the customSelect output [object HTMLDivElement], while the de outputs html code?

Comment: For you question 1 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870011/how-to-convert-javascript-code-to-jquery

For question 2, please be more specific.

Comment: Your jscustomSelect is html because you did `.html()` on the jquery object (like your `.innerHTML` on your non jquery object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery function should be like this

```
function reset(){
    var customSelect = $('.custom-select');
    var select = customSelect.find('select');
    select.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    customSelect.find('.select-selected').html(select.find('option:selected').html());
    customSelect.find('.same-as-selected').removeClass('same-as-selected');
}
```

Try this, but i'ts not easy to test it without your source code